# How to store $_POST data into session variable if the form name=an array?

Tags: php, session

I want to store the session data into a session variable so that it can be used in another php page other than the action="addbill.php" in form.But the problem is i want to store the array name[] into the session variable but shows error.

```
<form action="addbill.php" method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
     <br><input type="text" name="name[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['addedmem']= $_POST['name'];
 var_dump($_SESSION['addedmem']);
?>
```

```
<script>
                var counter = 1;
                var limit = 4;
                function addInput(divName){
                     if (counter == limit)  {
                          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                     }
                     else {
                          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
                          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                          counter++;
                     }
                }
</script>
```

Output Error:Undefined index: name

"ANY HELP IS WELCOMED"

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be an array

Comment: Yes to send it into SQL database, before doing some calculations

Comment: `addInput()` < where and what does that JS function do?

Comment: JS function dyanmically adds input field inaccordance with the user, when he clicks add another text input

Comment: @NitishRoat you don't need a variable to be an array to put it into an SQL database. The clarification is needed as there's an assumption that there will be multiple name[] inputs (hence you need it to be an array) but then you wouldn't add it as a session variable

Comment: If i have 5 or more { dynamic } different input fields with name="name", and i want all names in another php file then, without an array is it possible?? Other than the action="addbill.php" file.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your form input name to be a standard variable, not an array:

```
<form action="addbill.php" method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
     <br><input type="text" name="name">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If i need this data in another php file other than addbill.php file

Comment: Then you assign it as a session variable as you have done - $_SESSION['addedmem']= $_POST['name'];

Comment: It says Notice: Undefined index: name

Comment: Is this line - $_SESSION['addedmem']= $_POST['name']; - in your addbill.php?

Comment: Not in that file but in current

Comment: Thank You For your time, i would search it out.